# drupal search on the top taxnomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules, drupal-5

i have designed a view with 2 exposed filter

name(textbox) and place(taxnomy term with

xxxxx
-yy
-yy
-yy
these terms it works fine when i search for -yy terms, but the problem when i select on xxxxx
it should perform search on all the child terms (it should search even in -yy terms) but it seem to be happen , it only searches in the xxxx and gives empty results

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add these filter: Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth),
Depth: The depth will match nodes tagged with terms in the hierarchy. For example, if you have the term "fruit" and a child term "apple", with a depth of 1 (or higher) then filtering for the term "fruit" will get nodes that are tagged with "apple" as well as "fruit". If negative, the reverse is true; searching for "apple" will also pick up nodes tagged with "fruit" if depth is -1 (or lower).

Comment: but if i  am searching for apple i would like to get the results for only apple, if i search for fruits then only i need to get all the results to be displayed,,
can we have these settings based on each taxonomy terms,,,,, may be we can set taxanomy in depth for only one term, i m newbie in drupal ...

Comment: thanks nikit for ur help ,.,, but i dont want to create one more filter. with taxonomy term ID 
may be have to wirte any custom hook i m not sure....

Comment: hmm, i cannot understand, if you set depth=1 for fruit you will get all fruits and apples. Did not?

Comment: i have done in the same way , but i dint get any result. i just got blank result-
i have used a taxonomy with city, and given wait to 0 for all the terms..... does is effects , and i may i can use this taxonomy term ID with other filters in a view , i just got a blank result-
but i dint get any results....